# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{3^n+6^n-1}{6^n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{3^n+6^n-1}{6^n-1} = 1$

I proved the statement above but now the exercise says that I have to find $n_0$ so that $\left\vert x_n-1\right\vert < \frac{1}{50}$ with $(x_n)$ as the given seqeunce above.

I wrote the sequence like this: $(x_n)=\frac{3^n}{6^n-1}+1$ and then I looked at $\left\vert \frac{3^n}{6^n-1}+1-1\right\vert < \frac{1}{50}$ which is equivalent to $\frac{\frac{1}{2^n}}{1-\frac{1}{6^n}} < \frac{1}{50}$. But now I don't know how to go on...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Typo: You mean $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Are limit laws allowed? Or you need a $\epsilon$-$N$ proof?

Comment: Consider using logarithms, log function conserves the order of inequality

Comment: How can I solve the equation with logarithms? Can you show me?

Comment: Do you need the smallest $n_0$? Otherwise you can just calculate $x_{n_0}$ for some large number. If you need the smallest you can try the first few values

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2^{-n}}{1-6^{-n}}<\frac{1}{50}$ is equivalent to $2^n-3^{-n}>50$. By $3^{-n}<1$ if $n>1$ you get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{3^n}{6^n-1}$ is clearly decreasing for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we can just test numbers. If $n=5$ the inequality does not hold but with $n=6$ we get under $1/50$ so $n_0=6$ works.